# How do reviews work?

Tags: support

Lately I have been reviewing some questions and late answers. I have also seen first questions that lack quality, grammar or have other issues that do not appear in the review queue so I assume they have already been reviewed by someone.

What does it take for a question or late answer to be reviewed ?
If I review a question or late answer using the "I am done" button, does the question gets automatically reviewed or does it take more *quorum* to get in a reviewed state ?

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted) post from meta.SO.

Typically if you approve or reject a suggestion/flagged post, you are casting a vote. If someone else does that same, that action will be taken.

For an example, if you approve a Suggested Edit, it will still appear in someone else's queue and if both of you approved it, it will be approved side-wide and +2 rep will be added to the user.

If you rejected and someone else approved it, it requires a new vote to take that action.

If you rejected a particular post and if it was approved (with 2 votes) already, you will see a message "already approved/rejected" preventing you from casting new votes.

Note that this number, 2, can be different from site to site and per queue to queue. I don't how many votes does it require to apply that action. Hopefully some moderator here can complete the answer.